# WiX: Rename a folder during installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have very complex folders structure to install (dozens of folders/subfolders). 
I have prepared the whole structure with heat.exe, but some folder names have "template" names instead of the real ones.
Is it possible using WiX to rename the "templated" folders during the installation?
Say I have

> ```
> DirA
>   DirTemplate1
>     DirC
>   DirD
>     DirTemplate2
>   DirE
> ```

I can get real names for DirTemplate1 and DirTemplate2 via UI only.
Can I rename the folders after they are copied to the target?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you familiar with WiX. And explain a few variants how it could be done.

1. In directory table you named needed folders with CAPITAL letters, for example DIRTEMPLATE1. Then create dialog window and set this Directory with new value. During installation directory will be created with new folder name.
2. (Not recommended) Create custom action which will rename needed directories at the end of installation. Not recommended because uninstallation won't delete new folders, the Repair won't work as should.

Comment: All directory structure already created by heat.exe and I'm not sure how I can change the directory name automatically

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is simply not possible to do in a right way, it contradicts the installation ideology.
 I would accept such answer and start thinking on a different solution. Not all problems have a solution.